# Img upload help

Tags: image, avatar, uploader

i need coding in PHP where only registered users can upload as many images as they want with the option of deleting them .One of their image goes in their profile next to his/her details.

i want to store the images in server.

Comment: This looks more like a code request then a question...   
what have you got now, what have you tried?

Comment: ahha i know:D because i am soo tired to use my brain now

ok heres what i has done so far.My code uploads the server but doesnt send that to mySQL database at the end.

Comment: form:uploader.html<form action="uploader.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Select Image File :</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="userfile"  size="30" tabindex="1"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your User name :</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="username" tabindex="2" maxlength="25" size="30" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Enter Password  :</td>
    <td><input  type="password" name="password" tabindex="3" maxlength="20" size="30"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1) Store the image in a folder and store the location in the database

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

**or**

2) Pump the image straight into your database (then call a php file that gets it out and displays it based on the id)

http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx

Comment: sohnee i want to store location in database,but for registered members only.For that i had added username and password authentication in form.But i dont know how to make it work in php